# in List<User> users = [] ------ Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Tags: android, flutter

I'm raul and I need some help here

***THE ERROR***

> Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

****User class****

```
class User {
  final String Nome, Email, Senha;

  User({@required this.Nome, @required this.Email, @required this.Senha});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonuser) {
    return User(
        Email: jsonuser['Email'] as String,
        Nome: jsonuser['Nome'] as String,
        Senha: jsonuser['Senha'] as String);
  }
}
```

****Get class****

```
Future<List<User>> findExists() async {
  String urlLogReg = "https://weblogin.conveyor.cloud/api/login";
  var response = await get(Uri.parse("$urlLogReg?email=$EmailRL"),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.body != null) {
    var JsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(JsonData);
    List<User> users = [];
    JsonData.forEach((userData) {
      User user = User.fromJson(userData);
      users.add(user);
    }
   );
  }else{
    throw Exception('falha ao pegar dados');
  }
}
```

thank you so much for your help, have a great day

Comment: Console shows the line of the error? Which is the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the error is here :

```dart
    var JsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    JsonData.forEach((userData) {
      User user = User.fromJson(userData);
      users.add(user);
    }
```

as JsonData is a Map<String,dynamic> and in your anonymous function inside the for each you are just taking one item `userData` when you have two , the key and the value, hence the error.

This is your function inside the forEach
`(userData) {...}`

> (dynamic) => Null

Now for the solution, probably you should use the map method to convert the JsonData into User objects.

```dart
...

  if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.body != null) {
    var JsonData = json.decode(response.body)as List;// Presumably you are fetching a list of Users [] so i cast the result to a List
    print(JsonData);
    List<User> users = JsonData.map((e)=>User.fromJson(e)).toList();
//Here I can map passing just one argument because I casted my JsonData to a List and List's only have a value.
// Then i call toList() as the map method returns an Iterable ,not a List.
return users;
   );
  }
...
```

Hope this helps you I struggled a lot too with Json serialization in dart. If your projects start to grow in size I recommend you to use packages like json_serializable or a quick visit to https://app.quicktype.io .
Serialization is repetitive and error prone and if you can automate it , better.